# C# Concrete Class Inheriting from Closed Constructed Type

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I have a `Generic interface` declaring `Generic Method` as below.

```
 public interface BaseInterface<T> where T: class
    {
        //This will not generate the compile time
        //warning that the type parameter of method is same as interface
        U Method1<U>(U u) where U : T;

    }
```

Now I define a new `Concrete` class, inheriting a `closed constructed type` of the above interface.

```
public class DerivedClass : BaseInterface<string>
    {

        U BaseInterface<string>.Method1<U>(U u)
        {
            return "Some String";
        }
    }
```

In the interface, I have used the constraint on Type Parameter `U` as `where U : T`. Also I have used a closed constructed type where `T is string`. So in the `DerivedClass`, why wouldn't the compiler let me return a `string`?

**ERROR**:

> Error  CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'U'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) GenericPractice

Comment: Why not instead of `U Method1<U>() where U : T;` just do `T Method1() `?

Comment: I wanted the Method1 to work on the type parameter as same as that of the class.

Comment: I have modified the interface definition a bit now.

Comment: Imagine you had used BaseInterface<object>, you wouldn't be able to return new object(), when  U is a StreamReader...

Comment: Also, what do you expect U to be when T is a string? String is sealed. Why not return T?

Comment: @MineR. to answer your second question, I want my Derived Class to return a string. Also it is not the question of what I expect, but rather why is the error is coming ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting the error is because the compiler is not checking whether the class you specify as T is sealed, and then realizing that because U : T, means U must be T. If T is not sealed, the code can never work because any class could inherit T, and you can't convert between derived types without code to do so.

But based on your comments, I think you might just be looking for this:

```
public interface BaseInterface<T> where T: class
{
    T Method1<U>(U u) where U : T;
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseInterface<string>
{
    string BaseInterface<string>.Method1<U>(U u)
    {
        return "Some String";
    }
}
```

Please see the code above working at:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/aARD4W

Comment: this also gives me the error that the derived class doesnt implement BaseInterface

Comment: Please see the link in the answer, which shows the code working.

Comment: sorry. I didnt replace the return type of Method1 in the interface from U to T. Let me just try to understand your explaination

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply do this? Since in your code, `U` is `T`.

```
public interface BaseInterface<T> where T : class
{
    T Method1(T u);
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseInterface<string>
{
    public string Method1(string u)
    {
        return "Some String";
    }
}
```

You don't need the `where U : T` since you can just use `T` and since `U` is `T` then no need for `Method1` to be generic neither, since we know what type it'll return/need.

Test it here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/yFyZtc